# How long would it take to factor a RSA 128-bit key length?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

Ive done some research online and it seems to suggest the recommended key length for RSA encryption is 1024-bits. However i have a question as to how long would it take to factor a 128-bit RSA key length with an average computer used today? Is it possible and how long would it take?

Would much appreciate any help you could give me on this question!

Comment: @MikeChristensen he's talking about RSA keys, so of course it's asymmetric

Comment: Breaking a 512 bit RSA key costs around 100$. 128 is *much* cheaper.

Comment: did you manage to get an answer for this @ScottD?

Answer (score 4):

a implementation of a integer factorization algorithm like [elliptic curve method](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Method) (like [GMP-CGM](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/GMP-ECM)) will take a couple of seconds tops to compute the factors of a 128-bit RSA key on commodity hardware.