# Crypto++ Raw RSA sign short message with a short key

Tags: cryptography, rsa, crypto++

I have a message with a size limitation of 128 bit, which i want to sign and verify me as the originator. I have only one requirement : The cipher must not exceed the 128 bit limit.

So, after some research of the topic of signing and verification, i decided to use Raw RSA with a key-length of 128 bit, because i did not find any other suitable algorithms with fulfil the requirements. Other algorithms seem always to have some sort of memory overhead that need the cipher to be larger, but maybe i missed the correct ones (If so, it would be great to give me an hint)
I know, that this is crackable in no time, but the main requirement is the short message.

So at first, i tried to encrypt the message with the public key. I wanted to use the high-level schemes that Crypto++ provides (eg. `CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor`), but they have some sort of memory overhead for digests and other stuff, so i used [Raw RSA](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA) to do the calculations directly. 
My C++ code for en-/decryption looks like follows :

```cpp
// This is our message
std::string message = "0123456789ABCDEX";
CryptoPP::Integer m((const byte *)message.data(), message.size());
std::cout << "message ( "<< std::dec << m.ByteCount() <<" bytes)   : " << std::hex << m << std::endl;

// Generate keys
Integer n("0x3a1a51415e596a0d3e261661a35a68f99");   // modulus
Integer e("0x11");                                  // public exponent
Integer d("0x15dfbe36ba1ba36848b5d3ad478bb011");    // private exponent

RSA::PrivateKey privKey;
RSA::PublicKey pubKey;

privKey.Initialize(n, e, d); // Used for decryption
pubKey.Initialize(n, e); // Used for encryption

// Encrypt
CryptoPP::Integer c = pubKey.ApplyFunction(m); //generate cipher
std::cout << "cipher  ( " << std::dec << c.ByteCount() << " bytes)   : " << std::hex << c << std::endl;

// Decrypt
CryptoPP::Integer r = privKey.CalculateInverse(prng, c);
std::cout << "decrypted ( " << std::dec <<r.ByteCount()<<" bytes) : " << std::hex << r << std::endl;

if (r == m)
{
    std::cout << "Decryption successful" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Decryption failed" << std::endl;
}
```

Output :

```
message ( 16 bytes)   : 30313233343536373839414243444558h
cipher  ( 16 bytes)   : 2e294ff384751724c7dbbc31def66511h
decrypted ( 16 bytes) : 30313233343536373839414243444558h
Decryption successful
```

Now, in order to sign my message i need to use the private key for "encryption" and the public key for "decryption" (i quoted, since it's technically not an encryption). Under the above mentioned link, there is also a paragraph on how to perform [private key encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA#Private_Key_Encryption). There it is written, that one has only to switch the `e` (public exponent) and `d` (private exponent) parameters, when creating the pubilc and private key, and then follow the same steps like for encryption :

1. Encode the message
2. `ApplyFunction` (with the private key)
3. `CalculateInverse` (with the public key)

But this does not work, since `pubKey` has no `CalculateInverse`-method. So i tried a weird thing and now do the following

1. Encode the message
2. `CalculateInverse` (with the private key)
3. `ApplyFunction` (with the public key)

or in code :

```cpp
// This is our message
std::string message = "0123456789ABCDEX";
CryptoPP::Integer m((const byte *)message.data(), message.size());
std::cout << "message ( "<< std::dec << m.ByteCount() <<" bytes)   : " << std::hex << m << std::endl;

// Generate keys
Integer n("0x3a1a51415e596a0d3e261661a35a68f99");   // modulus
Integer e("0x11");                                  // now private exponent
Integer d("0x15dfbe36ba1ba36848b5d3ad478bb011");    // now public exponent

RSA::PrivateKey privKey;
RSA::PublicKey pubKey;

privKey.Initialize(n, d, e); // Used for signing (d and e are swapped)
pubKey.Initialize(n, d); // Used for verification

// Sign with the private key
CryptoPP::Integer c = privKey.CalculateInverse(prng, m); // 

std::cout << "cipher  ( " << std::dec << c.ByteCount() << " bytes)   : " << std::hex << c << std::endl;

// Verify with the public key
CryptoPP::Integer r = pubKey.ApplyFunction(c);

std::cout << "decrypted ( " << std::dec <<r.ByteCount()<<" bytes) : " << std::hex << r << std::endl;

if (r == m) { /* sucess */ } else { /* failed */ }
```

I'm heavily uncertain if this is the correct way of doing it. And why do i have to swap the exponents? It still works, even if i do not swap them.

Comment: What kind of encryption do you need? RSA is definitely not the answer, breaking 128 bit RSA [could almost be done on a pocket calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088524/589259).

Comment: My 7-year-old desktop computer factored your modulus `n` in a fraction of a second. 128-bit RSA offers no security whatsoever. You need at least 1024 bits.

Comment: I knew it would be not be very secure, but this is depressing. I have to sign a 128 bit message, and the cipher length must not exceed this length. I found that RSA fits this requirement, but with the drawback of insecurity. Do you know other (asymetric sign) algorithms, whos cipher has the same length as the input message, which are more secure?

Comment: Elliptic curve cryptography can get by with shorter keys, but its signatures are twice the key length. That means you would have to settle for 64-bit ECC at best. That's still not secure by any means.

Comment: Thank you! I guess it's still way more secure, than a 128 bit RSA Signature. But since cryptographic security is not the main goal, it would be ok for my purposes.

Comment: The smallest defined curve size that I know of is `secp112r1`, offering little to no security. The signature size would still be 224 bits though. secp128r1 BLS signatures would be 128 bits, but would offer even less security. If cryptographic security is not your goal, then you don't need a signature... If your use case fits symmetric algorithms then try HMAC and use the leftmost 128 bits.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you. Yeah, i know, that all of these solutions have nearly no security, but i didn't find a proper solution. I want to sign license keys and they have to be as short as possible (to be transmitted via phone in worst case). I found HMAC as well, but there i have to put the secret for validation along with the program (in source), which i wanted to avoid. So i found no better solutions, than the above mentioned.